# Hyper-V Cannot be installed: Virtualization is disabled in the firmware

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, macbook, hyper-v, hypervisor

I have installed Windows 10 Education on a [Macbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook) using Boot Camp Assistant. I have problem with running windows server using Hyper V, because I cannot select one of the options from window "Turn Windows Features on or off." When I try to select Hyper-V Hypervisor I get information like this: "Hyper-V Cannot be installed: Virtualization is disabled in the firmware". I have found some help about BIOS settings, but still I'm not able to do anything because it is a Macbook.

Comment: What is your CPU? It might be that your CPU does not support virtualization.

Comment: Which MacBook? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026757/windows-10-find-out-how-many-cores-your-processor-has shows how to find the CPU and the screen it leads you to will show if you can run Hyper-V as this example shows https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7868661

Comment: CPU- i5-5257U 2,70Ghz, I read K7AAY's article, I will try to instal Parallels Desktop and I will give u information if it really works. Do u know any different methons to run HyperV on mac? I guess, Parallels will be pretty slow

Comment: While Parallel's is type 2, that in itself won't make it "pretty slow."  For one or two VMs, what matters is your CPU speed, amount of RAM, and if you've got an SSD.

Comment: Oh, ok, so I have to use Parallels or VMware Fusion for Hyper-V to work, both programs are paid, which is not encouraging, there is no other option, right?

Answer (score 0):

If we install OS X and windows 8 or windows 8.1.
This seems to have something to do with how you boot the Windows partition.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120361/how-to-turn-on-hardware-virtualization-on-late-2013-macbook-pro-for-windows-8-1/122071#122071

It suggests rebooting into OS X, choosing BOOTCAMP from the Startup control panel, and then booting into Windows. This enabled virtualization on my machine. (I had previously booted into Windows using the Boot Camp Assistant, and virtualization was disabled.)

If we install windows 10
When we turn on Hyper-V feature ,we cannot boot into Windows again.
When we disable the Hyper-V feature, we can boot into Windows.

It is because of the discontinuance of support for CSM (Compatibility Support Module, which basically allows legacy BIOS stuff to work on new UEFI based systems) in the newest MacBook Pro models.

We can refer to it:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7771861

So we can consider Fusion, Parallels or VirtualBox.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj945424(v=win.10)

Comment: The referenced apple.stackexchange.com question now comes with another answer that doesn't bother with rebooting: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234819